# Another Call to a member function get_segment() on a non-object question

Tags: php, object, member

I get the above error when calling this code:

```
<?
class Test1 extends Core {
function home(){
?>
This is the INDEX of test1
<?
}
function test2(){
echo $this->uri->get_segment(1); //this is where the error comes from
?>
This is the test2 of test1 testing URI
<?
}
}
?>
```

I get the error where commentated.

This class extends this class:

```
<?php
class Core {

public function start()
{
require("funk/funks/libraries/uri.php");
$this->uri = new uri();
require("funk/core/loader.php");
$this->load = new loader();

if($this->uri->get_segment(1) != "" and file_exists("funk/pages/".$this->uri->get_segment(1).".php")){
include("funk/pages/". $this->uri->get_segment(1).".php");
$var = $this->uri->get_segment(2);
if ($var != ""){
$home= $this->uri->get_segment(1);
$Index= new $home();
$Index->$var();


}else{
$home= $this->uri->get_segment(1);
$Index = new $home();
$Index->home();

}

}elseif($this->uri->get_segment(1) and ! file_exists("funk/pages/".$this->uri->get_segment(1).".php")){

echo "404 Error";

}else{
include("funk/pages/index.php");
$Index = new Index();
$Index->home();
//$this->Index->index();


echo "<!--This page was created with FunkyPHP!-->";
}
}
}
?>
```

And here is the contents of uri.php:

```
<?php
class uri
{
    private $server_path_info = '';
    private $segment = array();
    private $segments = 0;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $segment_temp = array();
        $this->server_path_info = preg_replace("/\?/", "", $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]);
        $segment_temp = explode("/", $this->server_path_info);
        foreach ($segment_temp as $key => $seg)
        {
            if (!preg_match("/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-]+)/", $seg) || empty($seg)) unset($segment_temp[$key]);
        }
        foreach ($segment_temp as $k => $value)
        {
            $this->segment[] = $value;
        }
        unset($segment_temp);
        $this->segments = count($this->segment);
    }

    public function segment_exists($id = 0)
    {
        $id = (int)$id;
        if (isset($this->segment[$id])) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public function get_segment($id = 0)
    {
    $id--;
        $id = (int)$id;
        if ($this->segment_exists($id) === true) return $this->segment[$id];
        else return false;
    }
}
?>
```

i have asked a similar question to this before but the answer does not apply here.

I have rewritten my code 3 times to KILL and Delimb this godforsaken error! but nooooooo....

EDIT:
I have changed the core class to add __construct:

```
<?php
class Core {
function __construct(){
require("funk/funks/libraries/uri.php");
$this->uri = new uri();
require("funk/core/loader.php");
$this->load = new loader();
}

public function start()
{

if($this->uri->get_segment(1) != "" and file_exists("funk/pages/".$this->uri->get_segment(1).".php")){
include("funk/pages/". $this->uri->get_segment(1).".php");
$var = $this->uri->get_segment(2);
if ($var != ""){
$home= $this->uri->get_segment(1);
$Index= new $home();
$Index->$var();


}else{
$home= $this->uri->get_segment(1);
$Index = new $home();
$Index->home();

}

}elseif($this->uri->get_segment(1) and ! file_exists("funk/pages/".$this->uri->get_segment(1).".php")){

echo "404 Error";

}else{
include("funk/pages/index.php");
$Index = new Index();
$Index->home();
//$this->Index->index();


echo "<!--This page was created with FunkyPHP!-->";
}
}
}
?>
```

but now it says: Cannot redeclare class uri in /home/afsadad/public_html/private/funkyphp/funk/funks/libraries/uri.php  on line 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are requiring a classfile on line three... use require_once(), or a class autoloading function.

Answer (score 1):

When calling

```
$this->uri->get_segment(1);
```

the member `$this->uri` is not an object; probably it is not defined at all. I guess that your object's `Core::start()` method that defines `$this->uri` is not called prior to `Test1::test()`. Perhaps you wanted to initialize it in the constructor, `__construct()`?

Comment: i've edited the OP with __construct but now it comes with a new error. Please see edited OP.

Comment: well you both helped me, shame i can't amrk you both as correct or upvote

Answer (score 0):

```
$CI =& get_instance();
echo $CI->uri->segment(1);
```

Comment: Wont this create a deprecated notice?